# openGL ES 2 - Is there a way to attach a stencil buffer with a different resolution than the target texture?

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, stencil-buffer

I have an input texture in a certain resolution, and a target texture (attached as `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`) which is in a bigger resolution. I am using `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)` to upscale the input and draw some stuff on the target.

I have a buffer which is in the same resolution as my input that I would like to use as `GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`. 
Is it possible to attach it somehow without getting an error of `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to attach textures with different sizes to a framebuffer.

The [OpenGL-ES 2.0 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) states in Section 4.4:

> The framebuffer object target is said to be framebuffer complete [...] if all the following conditons are true:
>
> - All attached images have the same width and height.

If this is not the case, the framebuffer status has to return `FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS`.